# Can't provide ws traffic through nginx

Tags: http, nginx, websocket

There are WebSocket and HTTP servers running on my machine. I'm using Nginx to serve traffic for them.
When I do config for http it's working great.
But when I trying to serve ws, all routes go to http

My config:

```
http {
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }
 
    upstream websocket {
        server myapp:port;
    }
 
    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass ws://myapp:port;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }
}
```

When I go to `ws://myapp:port` I got a ws connection, but when I go to `ws://myapp:80` (like in nginx config) - I got http connection instead. It goes to nginx hello page: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNQVp.png)

I've tried to use many configs from other sources, but nothing works.

Maybe it's an error in another place?

Thanks a lot for help!

P.S. WebSocket server is on Python websockets and it's working great, but I need nginx to balance traffic and add SSL.

Comment: I think you should change ws to http in the line which you set the proxy_pass.

Comment: Hi @abarazal, I’be tried that way too. No results